# Error in mvc resource for insertion of css

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, hibernate, spring-mvc

Showing error as:

> ```
> Multiple annotations found at this line:
>   - Cannot locate BeanDefinitionParser for element [resources]
>   - Configuration problem: Cannot locate BeanDefinitionParser for element [resources] Offending resource: 
>    file
> ```

I am using spring 3.0.1 and hibernate 4. Even tried with other versions of spring but still shows the same.

```
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"   
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
         xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
       https://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">


        <context:component-scan
            base-package="Model,Controller,Dto,Service,Dao" />

         <bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
            id="jspViewResolver">
            <property name="viewClass"
                value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"></property>
            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>

        </bean>  





    <mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
      <mvc:mapping path="/**"/>
      <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
       class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
       <property name="paramName" value="locale" />
      </bean>
    </mvc:interceptor>

     </mvc:interceptors>




          <mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>
      <mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**" />

    </beans>
```

My spring-servlet code is as below in image

[image]

attached the code here

The code is attached please have a look at it and try help to solve this issue i have tried with spring 4 and it shows the same

Comment: Add the code as text and format it with CTRL + K so it's correctly displayed. Don't post code as image since it's harder to read, copy and edit.

Comment: Please help me.